# Add columns to a table or records without duplicates in Duckdb

Tags: python, sql, duckdb

I have the following code:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, PatternMatchingEventHandler
import duckdb

path = "landing/persistent/"
global con
con = duckdb.connect(database='formatted/my-db.duckdb', read_only=False)

class EventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, query):
        PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(
            self,
            patterns=["*.csv"],
            ignore_directories=True,
            case_sensitive=False,
        )
        self.query = query
    
    
    def on_created(self, event):
        filename = event.src_path.split("/")[-1]
        filename_trunc = filename.split(".")[0]
        try:
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query.format(filename_trunc), 
                           [event.src_path])
            
            cursor.execute("show tables")
            print(cursor.fetchall())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()

query = "CREATE TABLE {} AS SELECT * FROM read_csv_auto(?);"
event_handler = EventHandler(query)
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

It basically waits for a file in the path and adds it to the db as a new table.
However, I have two extra use cases:

- Add a new csv with the some modifications (with a table already created for that filename) and maybe some rows already exist in the table.
- Add a new csv with a new column (with a table already created for that filename)

However, I don't know how efficiently keep track of these two cases using sql nor duckdb.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CREATE OR REPLACE` syntax to create the table if the table does not exist and replace if the table exists.

```
query = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {} AS SELECT * FROM read_csv_auto(?);"
```

This option will basically drop and recreate the table every time you have a csv file with the same name as the table.

OR

You can use `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax to create the table only if it does not already exist.

```
query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} AS SELECT * FROM read_csv_auto(?);"
```

Next you will have to build some logic in python to update rows or add columns.
You could try [loading the csv file](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) first as pandas DF.
Then use duckdb and pandas DF features linked below.

https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/sql_on_pandas
https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/import_pandas
https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/export_pandas